# Run Android google calendar on my device

Tags: android, github, google-calendar-api

How can I download this [source project](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar) from GitHub and run it from my Eclipse IDE and on my device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Check out the entire source code for Android.

Step #2: Build the entire source code for Android, including the calendar app.

Step #3: Pour the results of Step #2 into a ROM mod for your device.

Step #4: Replace the firmware of your device with that ROM mod.

IOW, usually you cannot just take an arbitrary app out of the AOSP and build it independently, because it will have dependencies on the rest of the Android source code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) <br/>
If I just want the code of the calendar to get inspiration for my own app, the only solution is to read the source ?? Can't i get in parallel a app running to see the result ??

Comment: @ElielHaouzi: You can "get in parallel an app running" by following the above instructions. I repeat: usually you cannot just take an arbitrary app out of the AOSP and build it independently, because it will have dependencies on the rest of the Android source code.